# How can I convert my "price" column from string to number format?

Tags: python

```
# Import required modules 

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

# Get data from webpage

mystocks = ['GOOG', 'META', 'MSFT', 'PLTR', 'TSLA', 'ZS', 'PYPL', 'SHOP', 'TTCF']

def getData(symbol):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; 
    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')    
    stock = {
    'symbol': symbol,
    'price': soup.find('div', {'class':'D(ib) 
    Mend(20px)'}).find_all('fin-streamer') 
    [0].text,
    }
    return stock   
        
def export_data(stockdata):
    df = pd.DataFrame(stockdata)
    df.to_excel("LETS GO2.xlsx")
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
    df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True: 
        stockdata = []    
        for item in mystocks: 
            print(item)
            stockdata.append(getData(item))
        export_data(stockdata)
        time_wait = 10
        print(f'Waiting {time_wait} minutes...')
        time.sleep(time_wait * 60)
```

I need to convert the "price" column into number format, but the solution `df["A"] = pd.to_numeric(df["A"])` does not work...no errors are presenting anymore (that was probably an issue with my code), but the exported excel is not returning the number data type as requested.

Appreciate all the help, thanks!

Comment: it's possible that you have some bad non-numeric values, you can try converting them to null using Pandas and the parameter `errors='coerce'`. This will convert any bad non numeric values to `NaN`. Try `df["A"] = pd.to_numeric(df["A"], errors='coerce')`

Comment: yeah I've tried that too with no luck...that removes the "unable to parse string" error, but still results in the price column exporting as text. Thanks for the help!

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: first edit question and put code with correct indentations. Next describe problem in question's body, not in title. And finally show FULL error message in question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and those should be fixed now, but lmk your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.optimize as sco
import datetime as dt
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
np.random.seed(777)


start = '2018-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'
# N = 90
# start = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N)
# end = dt.datetime.today()



tickers = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','CSCO','CVX','XOM','GS','HD','IBM','INTC','JNJ','KO','JPM','MCD','MMM','MRK','MSFT','NKE','PFE','PG','TRV','UNH','RTX','VZ','V','WBA','WMT','DIS','DOW']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Adj Close']])

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.dtypes
df.head()
df.shape

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
# By specifying col[1] in below list comprehension
# You can select the stock names under multi-level column
table.columns = [col[1] for col in table.columns]
table.head()
```

This is what you get.

[image]